# Invalidate match in batch file for loop

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have the following directory structure:

```
>C
    >SomeFile
        >.IgnoreMe
            >VitalSystemInfo.eiafj
            >DontTouchThis.ei3rw3j
        >Picture.jpg
        >Pandas.gif
        >Code.cpp
        >AnotherDirectory
            >MoreStuff.bacon
```

and I have a loop to go through it

```
for /R %f in (C:\SomeFile) do echo %f
```

How can I exclude `.IgnoreMe`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be a little confused about the syntax of `for /r`.  It should be

```js
for /r "folder" %f in (filemask) do echo %f
```

You should also double-pump the percent signs if you're putting this in a .bat script.

---

Anyway, if all you're doing is `echo`ing the results, then the easiest way to exclude ".IgnoreMe" would be to pipe the output into `find /v ".IgnoreMe"`.

```js
for /r "c:\SomeFile" %%f in (*) do echo %%f | find /v /i ".IgnoreMe"
```

On the other hand, if your use of `echo` was merely for demonstration but not actually production, then you can accomplish the same effect with a `for /f` loop executing `dir /s /b`.

```js
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /b "c:\SomeFile" ^| find /v /i ".IgnoreMe"') do echo %%f
```

If you want to get really fancy, you could take advantage of the fact that `for /d` excludes hidden folders.

```js
attrib +h "c:\SomeFile\.IgnoreMe" >NUL 2>NUL
for /d /r "c:\SomeFile" %%I in (*) do (
    for %%J in ("%%~I\*") do echo "%%~fJ"
)
```

Even though that's more code, it is more efficient (faster) than excluding with `find /v`.  You'll often find that internal `cmd` functions execute more quickly than executables such as `find.exe`.